# node variable from one file in another is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I am tryin to access vaiable of one node file in another

But the value is undefined

FILE : app.js :

```
var P = 4000;
module.exports = app;
module.exports = P;
```

FILE : www/bin :

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = require('../config')[env];
var PORT = config.dataServer1.port;
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('backend:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || PORT);

var p = app.P;

console.log("P : " + p);
```

In Colsole.log :

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node .\bin\www`
P : undefined
Server listening on PORT : 3000
```

It says that "P : undefined"
I am not able to access the value of variable P in another file.

Please help
-Ashish

Comment: import app like this - var app = require("../../app");

Answer (score 0):

### app.js

```js
var p = []
p.push(1)
p.push(2)
module.exports = { p }
```

### main.js

```js
const app = require('./app.js')
console.log(app, app.p)
```

### Output

`{ p: [ 1, 2 ] } [ 1, 2 ]`

Comment: I am asigning the value of p in app .js using some logic. For siplicity sake I gave this example where ps is assigned before export.
is it possible to export the variable which is assigned earlier?

Comment: Yes you can do that, I have updated my answer to explain

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked :
app.js:

```
serverPort = function () {
  return config.dataServer1.port;
}
module.exports = app;
module.exports.PORT = serverPort();
```

main.js :

```
console.log("SERVER : " + app.PORT);
```